# why it does not console.log

Tags: javascript, html

I have written code that I thought should just print out some plain text

`<script>alert(0)</script>`

into the console

```
<script>    

const str = '<script>alert(0)</script>'
console.log(str)

</script>
```

Why won't the above code print
`<script>alert(0)</script>`
into console
but `' console.log(str)` into the body?

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1b5js8fy/

Comment: Your script ends where the first `</script>` is.  Consider `const str = "<script>stuff</scr" + "ipt>"` or similar

Comment: thank you, but is there any ways to assign string normally

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `/` character within `</script>` otherwise it will be treated as a closing tag.

```
<script>    
    const str = '<script>alert(0)<\/script>' // notice \/
    console.log(str)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML parser starts a script element when it encounters an opening `<script>` tag, and passes all HTML source up to the next `</script>`, along with attribute values of the opening tag to the JavaScript engine to create a script object.

If the JavaScript code needs to contain `</script>` it must be written differently to avoid being detected by the HTML parser.

A typical solution is to backslash the forward slash in code strings:

```
 <\/script>
```

where the backslash escape `\/` sequence is resolved to a single forward slash without being treated as the HTML end script tag.

Note the issue does not relate to environments which are *not* being parsed by the HTML parser first, such as when including external scripts using `scr` attribute on the opening tag of a script element pair in HTML:

```
<script src="http:example.com/myscript.js"></script>
```

or in non HTML environments such as under nodejs.